# How do I create a panel of line graphs, where each graph has its own y- and x-axis?

Tags: r

I would like to create multiple line plots where x=year and y=proportion of missing values and "Unknown" values, and then arrange them (row x column) so that each column corresponds to a particular demographic variable and each row corresponds to a particular pathogen.

Here is a sample of my data, `df`:

```
    PATHOGEN      Year Variable   Group      Proportion
    Campylobacter 1995 Age        Missing    0.09384
    Campylobacter 1995 Age        Unknown    0.00000
    Campylobacter 1995 City       Missing    0.40548
    Campylobacter 1995 City       Unknown    0.00000
    Campylobacter 1995 County     Missing    0.11610
    Campylobacter 1995 County     Unknown    0.00000
    Campylobacter 1995 Gender     Missing    0.00000
    Campylobacter 1995 Gender     Unknown    0.05479
    Campylobacter 1995 Serotype   Missing    0.00000
    Campylobacter 1995 Serotype   Unknown    0.10582
```

Note that the dataframe contains 4 different factors for `PATHOGEN` and a wide numeric range for `Year`, and that I am grouping the lines by `Group` for each value of `Variable` (i.e., the demographic variables).

I have been partially able to accomplish my goal with the following code using the `ggplot2` package:

```
    plot<-ggplot(df, aes(x=Year, y=Proportion, group=Group, colour=Group)) + geom_line()
    plot1<-plot + facet_grid(PATHOGEN ~ Variable, scales="free", space="free")`
```

However, this does not give me independent scales for each plot, but rather independent scales for each row. I assume this is because such a feature is not available when using `facet_grid`, while I'd prefer each panel have its own y- and x-axis (i.e., some pathogens have no data for the early years of the range, and thus are squished on the far right side of their panel).

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Is there a way to do this without significant data manipulation? Thanks.

Comment: the [gridExtra](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/index.html) package should be able to help. you'll need to build each 'panel' separately and stitch them together with `grid.arrange()`

Comment: Try using `facet_wrap()` instead of `facet_grid()` (keeping the option `scales = "free"` that you are already using).

Comment: @konvas that's it! Cheers, friend!